# Add Columns to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I fill my list with properties, and I want this list to be the datasource of my dataGridviiew.

But when I set this list to dataGridView as dataSource all the property values are in one column. How can I add a column in dataGridView for each property?

Here is my code:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{       
    Restaurant n = new Restaurant );

    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView2.SelectedCells)
    {
        IList<String> lista = new List<String>();
        n.Data = string.Empty;
        n.Data2 = string.Empty;
        int indexOfYourColumn = 9;
        int index2 = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            n.Data = row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value.ToString();
            n.Data2 = row.Cells[index2].Value.ToString();
            if (cell.Value.ToString() == n.Data.ToString())
            {

                lista.Add(n.Data);
                lista.Add(n.Data2);
                dataGridView3.DataSource = lista.Select(x => new { Value = x }).ToList();

            }
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: You have  only one property ("Value"), thats why the data ends up in just one column. You need to Pivot the data or create a structure that has the properties you want and create an enumerable list of them.

Comment: @user4861279, if you have a new question, please create a new question instead of editing your old question.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen I have problem with adding new question, please help here if you know :)

Comment: @user4861279, what's your problem with adding new question? Was there any message when you try to add a new question?

Comment: @Handoko.Chen yes,I'm blocked

Comment: @user4861279, I asked in the chat room and someone gave me this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997). Please read it. That's all I can do for you.

Comment: Please refrain from defacing your posts in this manner. If you are unable to post new questions, work on getting yourself unbanned by following the advice in the link provided by Handoko.

Comment: Thank you very much that you "helped me" here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something like this, even though I'm not sure since it's a bit unclear from your code.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    /* Place indexes here, there is no need to initialize   *
     * so many integers inside loop if they're not changing */
    int indexOfYourColumn = 9, index2 = 0;

    var restaurantList = new List<Restaurant>();
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView2.SelectedCells)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (cell.Value.ToString() == row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value.ToString())
            {
                restaurantList.Add(new Restaurant()
                {
                    Data  = row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value.ToString(),
                    Data2 = row.Cells[index2].Value.ToString()
                });
            }
        }
    }

    dataGridView3.DataSource = restaurantList;
}
```